# correct syntax for 'IF NOT EXIST'

Tags: mysql

What is the correct why to create a temp table?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE indexed_temp IF NOT EXIST
  temp_table ( INDEX(locationcode) ) 
AS (
  SELECT customerid, locationcode
  FROM cardbatch
)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE indexed_temp2 IF NOT EXIST
  temp_table ( INDEX(cia_locationid) ) 
AS (
  SELECT cia_customerid, cia_locationid
  FROM cardinventoryalerts
)



ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXIST   temp_table ( INDEX(locationcode) )  AS (   SELECT customerid, loc' at line 1
```

Comment: The documentation for [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) is **abundantly** clear on how this works. Have you read it?

Comment: I used the first sample   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: @Brad The error doesn't match the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@brad, pay attention in your code.

You're writing `IN NOT EXIST` instead of `IF NOT EXISTS`.

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE indexed_temp IF NOT EXISTS (...)`

And as @tadman said, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) is very clear and helpful :)

Comment: Weird because the error reads "'IF NOT EXIST   temp_table ( INDEX(locationcode) )  AS (   SELECT customerid, loc' at line 1" (still incorrect, but IF, not IN)

Comment: And what about EXIST/EXISTS ?